# Ionic infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework, underscore.js

I am using wordpress as a backend for an app and I want to use infinite scroll but I am having trouble concatenating articles.

I am calling the service using a factory:

```
.factory('Worlds', function ($http) {
    var worlds = [];

    storageKey = "worlds";

    function _getCache() {
        var cache = localStorage.getItem(storageKey );
        if (cache)
            worlds = angular.fromJson(cache);
    }
    return {
        all: function () {
            return $http.get("http://www.examplesite.com/tna_wp/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=international&filter[posts_per_page]=10").then(function (response) {
                worlds = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
                return worlds;
            });
        },

        GetNewPosts: function () {
            return $http.get("http://www.examplesite.com/tna_wp/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=international&filter[posts_per_page]=2").then(function (response) {
                worlds = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
                return worlds;
            });
        },
        get: function (worldId) {
            if (!worlds.length) 
                _getCache();
            for (var i = 0; i < worlds.length; i++) {
                if (parseInt(worlds[i].ID) === parseInt(worldId)) {
                    return worlds[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    })
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
.controller('WorldCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $timeout, _, Worlds) {
    $scope.worlds = [];
    Worlds.all().then(function (data){
      $scope.worlds = data;
      window.localStorage.setItem("worlds", JSON.stringify(data));
    }, 

    function (err) {
      if(window.localStorage.getItem("worlds") !== undefined) {
        $scope.worlds = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("worlds"));
      }
    }
  );

  $scope.loadMore = function() {

    Worlds.GetNewPosts().then(function (worlds){
        var loadedIdss = _.pluck($scope.worlds, 'id');
        var newItemss = _.reject(worlds, function (item){ 
           return _.contains(loadedIdss, item.id); 
      });
      $scope.worlds = newItemss.concat($scope.worlds);
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
      });
    };

})
```

I am trying to use underscore to ignore the posts that are already loaded, however when i try the infinite scroll it just goes into a loop calling more posts but doesnt add them to my ng-repeat and ionicLoading renders the app useless.

Comment: can you please put your demo on http://play.ionic.io/ ?

Comment: @mudasserajaz I will give it a try. I have stripped a ton of stuff but will try get it working there

Comment: i have put your code in here, http://play.ionic.io/app/494791c2744d please fork it and edit it , so i can see what your problem is.

Comment: @mudasserajaz Ok forked it

Comment: share here forked link with your changes

Comment: @mudasserajaz sorry here is the updated fork: http://play.ionic.io/app/d69e63e35088

Comment: @mudasserajaz sorry here is the updated fork with underscore added: http://play.ionic.io/app/af04f4fe1997

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89154/discussion-between-mudasser-ajaz-and-letterman549).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ion-infinite-scroll` works with some sort of paginated result and you seem to feed your list with all the results.

Your API should look something like this:

```
http://www.examplesite.com/tna_wp/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=international&filter[posts_per_page]=2&filter[page]=1
```

notice I've added a page filter.

and your service responsible to fetch the data should look something like this:

```
.factory('dataService', function($http) {
   return {
      GetPosts: function(page, pageSize) {
        return $http.get("http://mywebservice/api/test/posts/" + page + "/" + pageSize);
      }
   };
});
```

Your controller

```
.controller('mainController', function($scope, dataService) {

    $scope.posts = [];
    $scope.theEnd = false;

    var page = 0;
    var pageSize = 10;

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
        $scope.loadMore();
      });

    $scope.loadMore = function(argument) {
        page++;
        dataService.GetPosts(page, pageSize)
          .then(function(result) {
            console.log('items fetched: ' + result.data.length);
            if (result.data.length > 0) {
                angular.forEach(result.data, function(value, key) {
                  $scope.posts.push(value);
                });
            }
            else {
                $scope.theEnd = true;
            }
        })
        .finally(function() {
            $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
        });
    };

})
```

would initialize an array of objetct - as you're doing - and a boolean which tells the directive `ion-infinite-scroll` when you've reached the end:

```
$scope.posts = [];
$scope.theEnd = false;
```

Then you can have some variables to control the pagination:

```
var page = 0;
var pageSize = 10;
```

I start loading when the view is loaded:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.loadMore();
});
```

`$scope.loadMore` then would increment the page number:

```
page++;
```

and call the service layer:

```
dataService.GetPosts(page, pageSize)
```

when I've reached the end of the stream I would set the variable:

```
$scope.theEnd = true;
```

to let the directive know we don't have other items to append.

```
.finally(function() {
    $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
});
```

`finally` is always called when the promise is resolved.

Instead of `ng-repeat` you can use [collection-repeat](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/) which should be much faster.

You can play with it [here](http://play.ionic.io/app/269e2cf7bb19).

Comment: Thanx so much for the answer! extremely detailed and I understood it the whole way through! I just have a question, I have been playing around with infinite scroll and in the meantime went with a `limitTo` approach and, as well as loading all available articles at once, I limit how many are displayed untill the user gets to the bottom. What do you think would be the wiser option to go with? Break results into pages or load all at once?

Comment: Break result into pages is my favourite solution cause it should be faster, especially if there's load of data to be fetched.

Comment: Glad I've helped. Cheers.

Comment: @abhi314: Cheers mate :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this create a function `infiniteScrollCompleteCancelLoadMore` and call it when you want to complete the scroll and you have reached the end of your list.

```
function infiniteScrollCompleteCancelLoadMore() {
        $timeout(function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
                $rootScope.canLoad = false;
            });
        });
    }


$scope.loadMore = function() {
   Worlds.GetNewPosts().then(function (worlds){
      var loadedIdss = _.pluck($scope.worlds, 'id');
      var newItemss = _.reject(worlds, function (item){ 
         return _.contains(loadedIdss, item.id); 
   });
  $scope.worlds = newItemss.concat($scope.worlds);
  infiniteScrollCompleteCancelLoadMore() // CHANGE HERE  
  });
};
```

and your HTML

```
<ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="loadMore()" ng-if="canLoad" distance="1%"
                         immediate-check="false"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

**OR** call This is you ***just*** want to cancel `loadMore loop`.

```
function infiniteScrollComplete() {
        $timeout(function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
            });
        });
    }
```