# How to stop infinite scroll on ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, infinite-scroll

how to stop infinite scroll on ionic framework ?

controller.js

```
    $scope.page=1;
    $scope.loadMore = function() {
    $http.get("http://localhost/getdata.php?page="+$scope.page).success(function(items) {
    $scope.posts = items;
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    $scope.page +=1;                                                                                
});
    };
```

template-name.html

```
<ion-infinite-scroll
    on-infinite="loadMore()"
    distance="1%">
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Comment: I answered a similar question few weeks ago. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32504231/219406) might help.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [documention](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/) :

> Once on-infinite is done loading new data, it should broadcast the
>   scroll.infiniteScrollComplete event from your controller

which you are doing in your code `$scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');` this will stop spinning of loader. But if there is no more data left to load you can use `ng-if` to stop further infinite calls.But for that you need to get some flag from your server which can tell to client that there is no data left.

```
<ion-infinite-scroll
    ng-if="moreDataCanBeLoaded"
    on-infinite="loadMore()"
    distance="1%">
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

And control value of `$scope.moreDataCanBeLoaded` from controller. Once this is `false`, no more data can be loaded.

Comment: Please be specific what did not work and update your question with what exactly you are doing.