# How to detect an "on scroll" event using angularJs & Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I come from a JQuery background and don't know if this is possible or not in AngularJS.

I am working on a project using Ionic framework & AngularJS

I am trying to capture the "on scrolling" event using angular.

Currently I use the following HTML to create a list of 20 items and the following code outputs the "test" string on the `console log` on page load. But when I scroll up or down the list the event doesn't seem to fire again.

I've been researching but I can't seem to come across a way to get the "on scroll event" after the page has been loaded.  At least `directive` doesn't get call when the user is interacting with the list, so I think this is the wrong approach.

How can I capture that event in angular? Is it possible?

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
      <div class="list" >
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in data.items" when-scrolled="loadMore()" >Item {{item}}</div>
      </div>
      </ion-content>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ["ionic"])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$ionicScrollDelegate) {

  $scope.myTitle = 'Template';

  $scope.data = {
    items : [],
    title : ''
  };

  for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    $scope.data.items.push(i);
  }
})
.directive('whenScrolled', function () {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log("test");
    };
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your approach.  `onscroll` is an HTML event you can use to call any JavaScript, so why does `<div onscroll="loadmore()">` not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked
I had to change the markup and the directives to work on Ionic library

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQOGZy

```
<ion-scroll direction="y" on-scroll="gotScrolled(this)" delegate-handle="homeScroll">
        <p>Stuff 1</p>
        <p>Stuff 2</p>
        <p>Stuff 3</p>
        <p>Stuff 4</p>
        <p>Stuff 5</p>
        <p>Stuff 6</p>
        <p>Stuff 7</p>
        <p>Stuff 8</p>
        <p>Stuff 9</p>
        <p>Stuff 10</p>
      </ion-scroll>
```

Comment: hi Jonathan. I am doing Dom manipulation in getScrolled function. And it is recommend to use angular directive for dom manipulation. how can I link on-scroll with directive?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason why you are creating your own directive ?
Ionic already has scroll events if you want to load more data.
In those situation the best thing to do is to switch to [collection-repeat](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/).

> collection-repeat allows an app to show huge lists of items much more
>   performantly than ng-repeat.
>
> It renders into the DOM only as many items as are currently visible.
>
> This means that on a phone screen that can fit eight items, only the
>   eight items matching the current scroll position will be rendered.

You can change your HTML using the new directive:

Item {{item}}

and add:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!theEnd" on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="50%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

before the closing tag of your content `</ion-content>`.

The directive  will be in charge to fetch the data for you.

I am suggesting to use `collection-repeat` but the same principle can be applied to `ng-repeat` as well. The first one is just faster when it deal with lot of data.

Your controller should look something like this:

```
$scope.loadMore = function(argument) {
        page++;
        dataService.GetData(page, pageSize)
          .then(function(result) {
            console.log('items fetched: ' + result.data.length);
            if (result.data.length > 0) {
                angular.forEach(result.data, function(value, key) {
                  $scope.data.items.push(value);
                });
            }
            else {
                $scope.theEnd = true;
            }
        })
        .finally(function() {
            $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
        });
 };
```

You have to remember to broadcast the event `scroll.infiniteScrollComplete` at the end of your fetch process.

You can read more on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32504231/219406).

Or play with this sample [here](http://play.ionic.io/app/269e2cf7bb19).

Comment: Thanks for that!.. No, there is no particular reason. I am just new to Angular and Ionic and is what i kept seeing around. I am only showing 12 items so an infinite scroll doesn't really apply. Do you know how can I also know which item is at the middle of the container?

Comment: I am afraid I don't. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the directive as,

```
app.directive('ngScroll', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("onscroll", function(event) {
            scope.$apply(attrs.ngScroll);
        });
    }
  };
});
```

And html as,

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in data.items" ng-scroll="loadMore()" >Item {{item}}</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: i put a console.log inside the bind and it never gets called when i scroll up or down

Answer (score 0):

we can use **on-scroll** or **on-scroll-complete** events on content then we need to call a function in the controller like below

```
<ion-view view-title="Wall">
    <ion-content **on-scroll-complete="checkScroll()"**>
        <div class="list" ng-repeat="w in data.wallList">
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Complete **tutorial** is given here http://freakyjolly.com/detect-ionic-view-page-bottom-load-infinite-data/